# How to Change the Order Increment ID and Prefix in Magento?

Tags: php, sql, magento, localhost

How to change the order increment ID and prefix in Magento? I was successfully run the SQL queries but I did not get the results into my frontend magento.

I am trying the query here local host/phpmyadmin in magnto  (`eav_entity_store`)..so how can I change my order prefix number?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71771/how-to-change-order-increment-prefix

Comment: check this http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i used this query for order increment

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='0000000000'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order' AND eav_entity_store.store_id = '1';
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='ORD'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order' AND eav_entity_store.store_id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id` = '1' WHERE `eav_entity_store`.`entity_store_id` = 1;

You can update invoice_id also.