# How to change Order Id series in magento?

Tags: magento

I am working on magento.I want to change the series of order Id's.  can I have the orders starting from 400000026 instead of 100000026 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change the Order Increment ID and Prefix in Magento?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701686/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this from `eav_entity_store` Table. You need to change in `increment_prefix` field as per the entity type.

You can confirm entity type by click on `entity_type_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query on magento database.

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id` = '400000025' WHERE `entity_type_id` = STOREID;`
```

Replace STOREID with your store_id.